# In TYPO3 8.7 is it possible to give any content element a custom CSS class?

Tags: css, content-management-system, customization, typo3-8.x

I searched for this easy question, but didn't really find a satisfying answer. So is there a way to give any content element a custom class in TYPO3 8.7? If so, how do you do this? Is there an extension that enables you to do this or makes this easier?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can give custom css class to any content element with the help of Frame Class:

Add below script in Page TSConfig of your root page(Page->Rootpage->Resources->Page-TSConfig).

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.frame_class {
         addItems.101 = Custom Frame Class
}
```

then, add below script into ts file.

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
key.field = frame_class
  101 = TEXT
  101.value = <div class="Your-custom-class">|</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain this a bit further? Where do I specify what element should get my class? Where do I have to make changes? What does each line do? I don't know a lot about TypoScript.

Comment: Have you added frame class first? for check frame class is added or not got to any content element and then go to Appearance tab. on that tab check in dropdown name with Frame. "Custom Frame Class" name has been added in drop down.

Comment: First step is register frame class and add frame class to tt_content, second step is wrap your custom class to content element in frontend. custom class is apply to content element which class you select in drop-down into backend for particular content element.

Comment: Hope you understand my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this extension:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/cewrap/stable/

[image]

It does not add the class to the element, but you can warp any element with a div with different attributes that you can set.